# Define a variable used in js and css

Tags: vue.js

For example, I want to define a global color `a = '#FFF'`, and reference it in js and css to make sure that there is only one color named `a` in the project. then when the value of `a` changed, `a` in js and css also changed. is that possible in vue?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... I was thinking about watchers `watch` in combination with CSS variables.

Maybe something like this?
Whenever `a` changes, the CSS variable `--a` changes aswell.

You can actually type in any color format you want. Hex, rgb, rgba...

```js
let v = new Vue({
   el: "#app",
   data: {
      a: "red"
   },
   watch: {
      a(val){
         document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--a", val);
      }
   }
})
```

```css
:root {
   --a: red;
}
#app {
   height: 100px;
   width:100%;
   background: var(--a);
   transition: background 500ms;
}

p {
   background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
   <p>Color: {{a}}</p>
   <input v-model="a">
</div>
```